# angular material form validation input border

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using angilar 5 reactive forms with material. when submittiing form I want to set value for the input. sometimes that input can be invalid and the validation is firing. i dont want to fire that validation after submit. I have tried as follows. It hides the validation message but the input's border is going to red color because of that material validation classes. How can I overcome this?

```
  <mat-form-field>
                      <input matInput type="number" id="depositAmountId"  formControlName="depositAmount">
                      <mat-error *ngIf="paymentMethodsForm.controls.depositAmount.errors">
                       <span *ngIf="paymentMethodsForm.controls.depositAmount.errors.min && paymentMethodsForm.controls.depositAmount.touched">
                          Deposit amount can't be zero or negative value.
                        </span>
                     </mat-error>
                <mat-form-field>


onSubmit() {
this.paymentMethodsForm.patchValue({ 'depositAmount': 0 });
    this.paymentMethodsForm.controls["depositAmount"].markAsUntouched();
     this.paymentMethodsForm.controls["depositAmount"].markAsPristine();
   this.paymentMethodsForm.controls["depositAmount"].updateValueAndValidity();

}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want to rest the form if the input is invalid?

Comment: yes, I want to go to the initial state with no validation after submit

Comment: You want to reset the form to initial state after submitting the form?

Comment: not exactly. only the forms validation should be go to initial state. the value of some inputs need to be changed.